# Is this a triangle?

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem, integer

## Task

Write a function/program that, given three positive integers `a`, `b` and `c`, prints a Truthy value if a triangle (any triangle) could have side lengths `a`, `b` and `c` and outputs a Falsy value otherwise.

## Input

Three positive integers in any sensible format, for example:

- three distinct function arguments, `f(2, 3, 5)`
- a list of three numbers, `[2,3,5]`
- a comma-separated string, `"2,3,5"`

You may *not* assume the inputs are sorted.

## Output

A Truthy value if a triangle could have the sides with the lengths given, Falsy otherwise.

## Test cases

```
1, 1, 1 -> Truthy
1, 2, 3 -> Falsy
2, 1, 3 -> Falsy
1, 3, 2 -> Falsy
3, 2, 1 -> Falsy
3, 1, 2 -> Falsy
2, 2, 2 -> Truthy
3, 4, 5 -> Truthy
3, 5, 4 -> Truthy
5, 3, 4 -> Truthy
5, 4, 3 -> Truthy
10, 9, 3 -> Truthy
100, 10, 10 -> Falsy
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest solution in bytes, wins. Consider upvoting this challenge if you have fun solving it and... Happy golfing!

Comment: [Related: count the number of triangles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/190949/count-the-number-of-triangles)

Comment: You ask: "is this a triangle?" Probably not, but who knows. Is anything _really_ a triangle?

Comment: @Lyxal I say you can be anything. I believe in you. Do _you_?

Comment: △ △ ▽ ▽ ◁ ▷ ◁ ▷ A B ␂

Comment: you should at least admit that your test-cases 1,2,3 are "borderline triangles" as the shorter sides summed give the longest side so you have a "triangle on a line" - while 100,10,10 definitely is false as 10+10 is shorter than 100

Comment: @eagle275 while I understand what you mean, I do not wish to allow degenerate triangles into the Truthy test cases! If it doesn't have three distinct sides, it is not a triangle!

Comment: @RGS, the problem with 1, 2, 3 isn't that it [doesn't have 3 distinct sides](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199353/is-this-a-triangle#comment474114_199353) (they are mutually distinct both as lengths and as line segments), but rather that 2 of the sides are contained in the other one.

Comment: @LSpice thanks for your message :) I thought I was using rigorous language when I called a "degenerate triangle" to a triangle in the conditions you just described. Was I inaccurate? Because what you said was what I meant.

Comment: @RGS, yes, [degenerate triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(mathematics)#Triangle) is the usual phrase for [that](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199353/is-this-a-triangle#comment474193_199353), and I didn't mean to object to it, only to the 'distinct sides' language.

Answer (score 36):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda l:sum(l)>max(l)*2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBDgIhDEX3nKJLMCykDAsn0ZO4wehkSACJMlFPj201aft@f3/bp6/3imM5nkeO5XKNkOfnVnQ2pxLfhB2O15ryDdzcHql2WHSqbevamOEscCkaaMErlN3z7slSXnzH5Ajf8e9PFgIzkFRB8sJJ/vcWDj9ByknDFw)

Checks if `a+b+c > max(a,b,c)*2`. If, say, `c` is the biggest one, this is equivalent to `a+b+c>2*c`, or `a+b>c`, which is want we want for the triangle inequality.

Comment: This is also what I had for Python! +1 for us :p

Answer (score 27):

## [CP-1610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument_CP1600) machine code ([Intellivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellivision)), 12 DECLEs<sup>1</sup> = 15 bytes

A routine taking \$(a,b,c)\$ into **R0**, **R1** and **R2** respectively and setting the carry if \$(a,b,c)\$ is not a triangle, or clearing it otherwise.

```
083     |         MOVR    R0,     R3
0CB     |         ADDR    R1,     R3
15A     |         CMPR    R3,     R2
02F     |         ADCR    R7
0D3     |         ADDR    R2,     R3
049     |         SLL     R1
159     |         CMPR    R3,     R1
201 002 |         BC      @@rtn
048     |         SLL     R0
158     |         CMPR    R3,     R0
0AF     | @@rtn   JR      R5
```

#### How?

Instead of testing:

$$\cases{a+b>c\\a+c>b\\b+c>a}$$

We test:

$$\cases{a+b>c\\a+b+c>2b\\a+b+c>2a}$$

The left parts of the inequalities are stored into **R3**. If the first test fails (when \$a+b\$ is stored into **R3** and compared with **R2**), the carry is set and added to the program counter (**R7**), forcing the next instruction to be skipped. Consequently, **R3** is not updated to \$a+b+c\$ and the last 2 comparisons are turned into:

$$\cases{a+b>2b\\a+b>2a}\Leftrightarrow\cases{a>b\\b>a}$$

which of course is never true, so the test is guaranteed to fail as expected.

All in all, this saves a branch which would have cost 1 extra DECLE.

#### Full commented test code

```
        ROMW    10                ; use 10-bit ROM width
        ORG     $4800             ; map this program at $4800

        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
        ;;  main code                                                    ;;
        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
main    PROC

        SDBD                      ; set up an interrupt service routine
        MVII    #isr,   R0        ; to do some minimal STIC initialization
        MVO     R0,     $100
        SWAP    R0
        MVO     R0,     $101

        EIS                       ; enable interrupts

        MVII    #$200,  R4        ; R4 = pointer into backtab
        SDBD                      ; R5 = pointer into test cases
        MVII    #tc,    R5
        MVII    #13,    R3        ; R3 = number of test cases

@@loop  MVI@    R5,     R0        ; R0 = a
        MVI@    R5,     R1        ; R1 = b
        MVI@    R5,     R2        ; R2 = c
        PSHR    R3                ; save R3 and R5 on the stack
        PSHR    R5
        CALL    tr                ; invoke our routine
        PULR    R5                ; restore R3 and R5
        PULR    R3

        MVII    #$80,   R0        ; R0 = '0'
        BC      @@draw

        MVII    #$88,   R0        ; or '1' if the carry is not set

@@draw  MVO@    R0,     R4        ; draw this character

        DECR    R3                ; next test case
        BNEQ    @@loop

        DECR    R7                ; loop forever

        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
        ;;  test cases                                                   ;;
        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
tc      PROC

        DECLE   1, 1, 1           ; true
        DECLE   1, 2, 3           ; false
        DECLE   2, 1, 3           ; false
        DECLE   1, 3, 2           ; false
        DECLE   3, 2, 1           ; false
        DECLE   3, 1, 2           ; false
        DECLE   2, 2, 2           ; true
        DECLE   3, 4, 5           ; true
        DECLE   3, 5, 4           ; true
        DECLE   5, 3, 4           ; true
        DECLE   5, 4, 3           ; true
        DECLE   10, 9, 3          ; true
        DECLE   100, 10, 10       ; false

        ENDP

        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
        ;;  ISR                                                          ;;
        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
isr     PROC

        MVO     R0,     $0020     ; enable display

        CLRR    R0
        MVO     R0,     $0030     ; no horizontal delay
        MVO     R0,     $0031     ; no vertical delay
        MVO     R0,     $0032     ; no border extension
        MVII    #$D,    R0
        MVO     R0,     $0028     ; light-blue background
        MVO     R0,     $002C     ; light-blue border

        JR      R5                ; return from ISR

        ENDP

        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
        ;;  our routine                                                  ;;
        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
tr      PROC

        MOVR    R0,     R3        ; R3 = a
        ADDR    R1,     R3        ; R3 = a + b
        CMPR    R3,     R2        ; is R3 greater than c?
        ADCR    R7                ; if not, skip the next instruction

        ADDR    R2,     R3        ; R3 = a + b + c (or still a + b if skipped)
        SLL     R1                ; R1 = 2b
        CMPR    R3,     R1        ; is R3 greater than 2b?
        BC      @@rtn             ; if not, return with the carry set

        SLL     R0                ; R0 = 2a
        CMPR    R3,     R0        ; is R3 greater than 2a?
                                  ; if not, the carry is set

@@rtn   JR      R5                ; return

        ENDP
```

#### Output

[image: output]

*<sup>screenshot from [jzIntv](http://spatula-city.org/~im14u2c/intv/)</sup>*

---

*<sub>1. A CP-1610 opcode is encoded with a 10-bit value (0x000 to 0x3FF), known as a 'DECLE'.</sub>*

Comment: Do you have to run this on your TV? Maybe an emulator is in order...

Comment: @S.S.Anne I'm doing 95% of the debugging on [jzIntv](http://spatula-city.org/~im14u2c/intv/). For real (much bigger) projects, I do upload the ROM to a real Intellivision from time to time.

Comment: Oh, so that *is* an emulator. The homepage was unclear.

Comment: I think this should state that it is in machine language, not assembly language. I see that the assembler mnemonics alone are typically four bytes per instruction. PS. +1 Very nice.

Comment: @bitchaser That's a fair point. Updated!

Answer (score 10):

## Java 8, <s>52</s> <s>49</s> <s>38</s> 26 bytes

```java
(a,b,c)->a+b>c&a+c>b&b+c>a
```

Port of [*@xnor*'s formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199355/52210) turns out to be shorter after all, by taking the input as three loose integers instead of a List/array.
-12 bytes thanks to *@xnor* for reminding me that the first 6-bytes formula I used in [my 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199354/52210) is actually shorter in Java:

\$(a+b>c)\land(a+c>b)\land(b+c>a)\$

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bVFNa8MwDL33V4gcioPV0DrJYSvLP1gvPY4dZNcd7lKnNG5hjP72TPlgJNmwkdDzk554PtGdVqfDZ2NKqmt4Jee/FwDOB3s9krGwa0sAXVWlJQ9G8BMQtgzQfTLxljmPBYc6UHAGduDhBRpBqNHEq4KkLsySpCn0UnOkZtuyLzddMntoulfuAGdeQOzD1fmPt3eguFcPtg5ig3w6qV9AYToGFDPSKSNFNQa4nM5IuUVNZ6h5S4b5FMgxGwM5q8yAbLbHGp/myBo37f3jXWdDx/nP6d6P/Vcd7DmpbiG5sFWh9IJkhJHUXTQyeoZI@sQMPzCIPJof)

**Explanation:**

```java
(a,b,c)->  // Method with three integer parameters and boolean return-type
  a+b>c    //  Return whether the sum of a and b is larger than c
  &a+c>b   //  and the sum of a and c is larger than b
  &b+c>a   //  and the sum of b and c is larger than a
```

---

**Previous <s>52</s> 49 bytes answer:**

```java
S->{S.sort(null);return S.pop()<S.pop()+S.pop();}
```

Port of [*@GB*'s Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199362/52210) with input as a Stack of Integers.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dZHBb4IwFMbv/hUvO5WIjYIeNpyJxyXMS4/LDhU6U62FtA8XY/zbWcHOAWahoemP7339eG/PT3yyzw91pri18M6lvowApEZhvngmYNMcAbZFoQTXkJG9q6AVSkUZ8uywfHPSnTArSIPESa8j97LIUWawAQ2vULPJ6sKoLQwSXSkVJEZgZTQwWhYlCZZ@H/s9udZJY1JWW@VMvNepkDkcXTzC0Ei9@/gEHtyyobBIZqF72gR3EIVxF0ROEfcVcRh1gTv2PWJXEvU9omHJPFz0wSKcd8HC3TIA80GOafg8JNNw1qyHlrZtaDW@75TSeyP@RpNKi53JuClo8d35vjaGnxsRGTBLuW05D3ygf@fNHlxvghXxlYzyPF8rRdJfcLYojrSokJZuhqg0ScdPL/A01jQjLPB/e61/AA)

**Explanation:**

```java
S->{                        // Method with Integer-Stack parameter and boolean return-type
  S.sort(null);             //  Sort the input-Stack
  return S.pop()            //  Check if the last largest value
         <S.pop()+S.pop();} //  is smaller than the lowest two values added together
```

Comment: It is funny that even though you compute the max with a bunch of ?: operators, you can still get it to be shorter than the other answer!

Comment: Wow! Just looking over the other answers and see we're letter for letter identical (save the C/Java diffs)! I swear I did mine on my own! T_T

Comment: @RGS Yeah, and the `?:` are actually shorter than using the `Math.max` builtin, since it can only take 2 arguments (`Math.max(Math.max(a,b),Math.max(b,c))` is longer than `(a>b?a>c?a:c:b>c?b:c)`). PS: as List with builtin streams it's even longer: [`L->L.stream().mapToInt(i->i).sum()>L.stream().max((i,j)->i.compareTo(j)).get()*2` (**80 bytes**)](https://tinyurl.com/sxey88j). That was my very first attempt, before I posted my answer and had the 51 bytes alternative. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen the lengths you have to go to just to golf in Java!!

Comment: @RGS That's why it's so fun and I'm still here after almost four years of code-golfing. Although Java will never win a code-golf contest, tbh. [Unless it's the only answer of course. ;P](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157146/52210)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen oh so you are saying you being around has nothing to do with [your apparent obsession with puzzles](http://twistypuzzles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=26889)? :D

Comment: @RGS Tbh, twisty puzzles and code-golfing are completely different tbh. I'm pretty good in code-golfing, but not so good in solving puzzles, despite my enormous collection. I have to resort to tutorials pretty often, although I currently have loads of unsolved puzzles for which I'm either the only or one of the only owners, so no tutorial are available. Tbh, I also don't collect twisty puzzles as much as I used to and already sold a few. I'm more focused on some of my other collections lately. Basically too many hobbies, but not enough time and/or money. XD

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I understand your pain :'( generally speaking

Comment: It looks like it's actually shorter to write out `a+b>c&b+c>a&c+a>b`: [TIO](https://tio.run/##bVFNa8MwDL33V4gcSoLV0DrJYSvLP1gvPY4dZNUd6VKnNG5hjP72TPlgJNmwkdDzk554PtGdVqfDZ8Ml1TW8UuG@FwCF8/Z6JLawa0sAU1WlJQccyhMQtgwwfeJoK5zHQkLtyRcMO3DwAk1IaJCjVU7K5Lw0inNasqLcNNuWfbmZUthD070qDnCWBcK9vxbu4@0dKOrVva19uEE5ndQvoDEZA1oYyZSRoB4DUk5nJNKipzP0vCXFbApkmI6BTFRmQDrbY41Pc2SNm/b@8a6zoeP853Tvx/6r9vYcVzcfX8QqX7qQVICBMl1kFTxDoFzMww8MIo/mBw "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor Ah, of course.. I actually used that approach initially in my 05AB1E answer, haha.. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 8):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```ruby
->*a{a.sort!.pop<a.sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf104rsTpRrzi/qERRryC/wAbILs2t/R9tqKMARlxA0khHwViHywgsYgwWMQYJcoFJkBpjsJQRWI0RTMpER8EUzDAFsblMwbogDBOIOQY6CpZQFpBpCMaxeqmJyRnxxTmZyakaxprVNYk6STrJNQUK0WCGThqEjo2t/Q8A)

A different approach, xnor's formula would be shorter but I'm satisfied with that.

Comment: +1, [I'll take it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199366/75323) then :)

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>6</s> <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
O;‹ß
```

-1 byte by porting [*@xnor*'s algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199355/52210).
-1 byte thanks to *@Grimmy* using a derived formula.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f3/pRw87D8///jzbSAcJYAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXLf3/rRw07D8//r/M/OtpQBwhjdYC0kY4xkDYC8o3BfGMdIyANJMHyxkBxI7C8EVTcRMcUTJvqmABpU6B6CG0C0W@gYwllGOgYglBsLAA).

**Explanation:**

The formula this program uses to determine if three side-lengths \$a,b,c\$ form a triangle is:

\$t=\frac{a+b+c}{2}\$
\$(a<t)\land(b<t)\land(c<t)\$

```python
O     # Take the sum of the (implicit) input-list
 ;    # Halve it
  ‹   # Check if it's larger than each of the values of the (implicit) input-list
   ß  # Get the minimum of those checks
      # (`P` can be used as alternative to check if all are truthy instead)
      # (after which this result is output implicitly)
```

---

**Original 6-byter:**

```
ÀĆü+‹P
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cMORtsN7tB817Az4/z/aSAcIYwE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/8MNR9oO79F@1LAz4L/O/@hoQx0gjNUB0kY6xkDaCMg3BvONdYyANJAEyxsDxY3A8kZQcRMdUzBtqmMCpE2B6iG0CUS/gY4llGGgYwhCsbEA).

**Explanation:**

The formula this program uses to determine if three side-lengths \$a,b,c\$ form a triangle is:

\$a+b>c\$
\$a+c>b\$
\$b+c>a\$

Which translates to the following code for 05AB1E:

```python
À       # Rotate the (implicit) input-list once towards the right: [a,b,c] → [b,c,a]
 Ć      # Enclose it; appending its head to itself: [b,c,a] → [b,c,a,b]
  ü+    # Sum each overlapping pair: [b,c,a,b] → [b+c,c+a,a+b]
    ‹   # Check for each whether it's larger than the (implicit) input-list:
        #  [a<b+c,b<c+a,c<a+b]
     P  # And check if all three are truthy by taking the product
        # (`ß` could be used as alternative, like in the 4-byter program above)
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: +1 simple enough, right?

Comment: Another alternative 5-byter: [`xsO‹ß`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/imL/Rw07D8//r/M/OtpQBwhjdYC0kY4xkDYC8o3BfGMdIyANJMHyxkBxI7C8EVTcRMcUTJvqmABpU6B6CG0C0W@gYwllGOgYglBsLAA)

Comment: [`O;‹ß`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXLf3/rRw07D8//r/M/OtpQBwhjdYC0kY4xkDYC8o3BfGMdIyANJMHyxkBxI7C8EVTcRMcUTJvqmABpU6B6CG0C0W@gYwllGOgYglBsLAA) is 4 bytes.

Comment: @Grimmy Ah smart, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, 19 bytes

```
->*a{2*a.max<a.sum}
```

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##NYzdCsIwDIXv@xS51BGLS9YLQX2RUSQrGwoOZGOgbHv2uqYK@fk45yTD1Hxid4mHayEzFWJ7eZ/FjlO/xrpE0DLbJARGQ6qwKpxEozNlWC3SDP2tCsEpuMTG6VWGKv85Ipx@tGGp7W0r4X4bn4/Q7ng/L4INhuUFtQJ2eXu/xi8)!

Uses the fact that [this Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199362/75323) said it didn't want to implement the port of [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199355/75323) and at the same time taught me enough syntax to guess how the max of an array is calculated :)

Comment: @S.S.Anne Please remember to follow the [Code of Conduct](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Comment: @Doorknob What did I do?

Answer (score 7):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 30 bytes

Probably the most basic formula.

```c
f(a,b,c){a=a+b>c&a+c>b&b+c>a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BCoMwEEX3nmIQKgmO0BhdFKl3mUQiQmulLe1CvHrTaRaSLEqSIe/9T2Kr0VrvnSA0aOVKZypNbwsqbW8Kw5O6zU/zE640zeJ1mwYJawaw3Fk6wTeA/DD8WzmGhhMK4bdlxDWC3rkOuY5zzZWddeirmFWc1yFP@g1CG3PLauc2vJ9wk/x/RDilgo0KR7KSXbb5j3UXGh@@en8B)

Comment: Good job recognising the more verbose formula ends up being shorter here! What is the leading `a=`? Is it for some kind of implicit return?

Comment: @RGS Yes. The way gcc compiles this, [assigning the value to a variable](https://godbolt.org/z/p3hksV) or [returning it](https://godbolt.org/z/Euq3p9) both put the result in `eax` and therefore lead to the same behavior.

Comment: I learned so much of C from this answer. I didn't know you could omit the type of parameters, return type, and return statement.

Comment: @user1754322 Just remember to only use it in code golf. This is formally undefined behavior in every C standard.

Answer (score 6):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>45</s> 32 bytes

```php
fn($a)=>max($a)*2<array_sum($a);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBNDsIgEEb3nmJCumgNNhbahemPB1FjiNF000pqTfT0yCBVO2wkLODx5gNGt9pUW91qiMbaXPo4UknddOqBi6Wo1DCo5/F273BfmvOpvQLLOOAEO1YNsDQa451nhyRl@56Vi48pOEhqIiOmcPVz07MwU9oImonsD1O62@k7pbspMLMwU7h6Qd8pQtPW5xwKmoksNAt7QE1kxCzcj@amZ6GZ0356Rru05rB5q99@ehaoluNZ9qtObJLNCw)

Lambda function that takes an array `[a, b, c]` and outputs empty string if false or "1" if true, with xnor's formula.

Note that in PHP the `;` is only necessary when the function is attributed to a variable, so it's placed in the footer (provided code is valid as it is).

EDIT: thanks to Guillermo Phillips for introducing me to PHP 7.4 short notation! (as a declaration without `{}`, it now needs the `;`)

Comment: Could you not use the short lambda syntax from PHP 7.4?

Comment: @GuillermoPhillips thanks a lot, I actually didn't know them, it doesn't appear on the manual (yet?)

Comment: Good job on this PHP answer and +1 for this lambda function!

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 12 bytes

```
2Max@#<Tr@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b738g3scJB2SakyEFZ7X9AUWZeSbSyrl2ag3Ksmr5DNVe1oQ4Q1uqAGEY6xiCGkY6CoY6CMURMwVhHwQjEBNFACSjTECpqBBaFKTDRUTCFMk2BPBDTFGwCjGkCM9dAR8ESzgZyDMG4lqv2PwA)

Comment: Thanks for teaching me smth! I'm assuming (1): the single @ can be used to call a function and (2): the trace of a list is its sum. Am I right?

Comment: @RGS Yup! and here are some "master tips"... https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12900/67961

Answer (score 6):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 5 bytes

```
$~\->
```

Why bother with any of the other math? If the longest side is longer (or equal) than the sum of the shorter two, it can't be a triangle. Otherwise it can.

Input is an array. Output is 0 or 1. If you have the list necessarily sorted, then you can just input as a dumped array (straight onto the stack) and the first two characters are unneeded. If the list can be entered in *reverse* order, then you can remove the first three characters and flip the greater-than to a lesser-than, leaving only 2 characters needed.

```
$~\->  #Check if side lengths could make a triangle
$      #Sort
 ~     #Dump array onto stack (stack is now 1 2 3)
  \    #Swap the top two elements (1 3 2)
   -   #Subtract the top from the second (1 3-2)
    >  #Check if that difference is strictly greater than the smallest value
```

This is equivalent to my last answer, but instead of a+b>c, I did a>c-b, which saves a character of stack-shuffling.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPkfbaxgomAe@1@lLkbX7v9/AA)

Comment: you are still using maths :D good job on this!

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```apl
+/>2×⌈/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X1vfzujw9Ec9Hfr/0x61TXjU2/eob6qn/6Ou5kPrjR@1TQTygoOcgWSIh2fw/0e9cxVCikpLMiq50g6tUNAwVABCTQUNIwUgBNLGCiYKpmDaVMEESJsqGENpEwVjIG1ooGAJZHCBzHFLzCmGG2MEljYCGgdWBtQGMc4IbLwxUNwIrN1AwRCENAE)

Also uses [xnor's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199355/78410) of `sum(a,b,c) > 2 * max(a,b,c)`.

#### How it works

```apl
+/>2×⌈/
+/       ⍝ Is sum
  >      ⍝ greater than
   2×    ⍝ twice of
     ⌈/  ⍝ max?
```

---

## Alternative 7 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```apl
∧/+/>+⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HHcn1tfTvtR70r/qc9apvwqLfvUd9UT/9HXc2H1hs/apsI5AUHOQPJEA/P4P@PeucqhBSVlmRUcqUdWqGgYagAhJoKGkYKQAikjRVMFEzBtKmCCZA2VTCG0iYKxkDa0EDBEsjgApnjlphTDDfGCCxtBDQOrAyoDWKcEdh4Y6C4EVi7gYIhCGkCAA)

#### How it works

```apl
∧/+/>+⍨
  +/     ⍝ Is sum
    >    ⍝ greater than
     +⍨  ⍝ twice each number?
∧/       ⍝ All of them?
```

Comment: Thanks for the submission +1 what is up with the weird character you are using in the explanations?

Comment: @RGS If you mean `⍝`, it starts a line comment in APL (just like `//` in C and `#` in Python).

Comment: @Bubbler But only C99 and after. It's commonly called a "C++-style comment".

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ṀḤ<S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzoaHO5bYBAMZ@6wfNcxR0LVTeNQw1/pwO9fh9kdNayL//4@ONtRRAKFYHQUQ00hHwRjENAKLGkNFjYESIKYxWIEhlGkIFTUCi8IUmOgomEKZpkAeiGkKNgHGNIGZa6CjYAlnAzmGYBwbCwA)

A monadic link taking a list of integers and returning a Jelly boolean (`1` = True, `0` = False).

Based on [@xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199355/42248) so be sure to upvote that one too!

### Explanation

```
Ṁ    | Maximum
 Ḥ   | Doubled
  <  | Less than:
   S | - Sum of original argument
```

Comment: +1 good job on the port :)

Comment: @RGS thanks. Nice series of questions recently!

Comment: thanks for your feedback, let's keep them coming!

Comment: Alternative 4 bytes: [`Ḥ<SẠ`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjiU2wQ93Lfj/cOc@60cNcxR07RQeNcy1PtzOdbj9UdOayP//o6MNdRRAKFZHAcQ00lEwBjGNwKLGUFFjoASIaQxWYAhlGkJFjcCiMAUmOgqmUKYpkAdimoJNgDFNYOYa6ChYwtlAjiEYx8YCAA) for "double of all elements less than sum".

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 31 bytes

```
\d+
$*
O`1+
^(?!(1+),(1+),\1\2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYqxCsMwDER3/UWhAae@wZLtIVPHjvkBExxohy4ZQv7fORtJT8fjzt/1P/Y2uU9t5evl@ZK1qpfNvR9O/YyBosXm1hQcURiiGHNkjjDh0Ucao7dhEjKZkSSz05l6P2AZL0D73g) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
O`1+
```

Sort.

```
^(?!(1+),(1+),\1\2)
```

Check that the sum of the first two is greater than the third.

Comment: These Retina solutions keep amusing me! +1

Comment: @RGS It's always nice when you can coax Retina to perform functions which seem unrelated to string manipulation.

Comment: Indeed!!! Now I want to see how Retina fares in the [count regex matches](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/199442/75323) challenge, which **is** related to string manipulation!

Comment: @RGS I can't see an obvious approach for that one sorry.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>54</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>42</s></sup> 36 bytes

Saved 6 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
f(a,b,c){a=a+b+c>2*fmax(a>b?a:b,c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJRa4MwEMff@ykOoaA1Mo3tQ@d0D2OfYspIYuyEaovxIUz86nMxGpmu8r9w@r/fRY5j3oWxYShsgihiTkdi4lKXJfhQVETaJKGv5Hl0on4o6xYqUta2s@t2oB72RZoDNB8ZxNBZqXzHqTy/qThZCP6@h1YfaWJs0XLRfpIJChAoYX2GWtgkJ63AH8Pf4nTBFxabVkcNhjo5j/QWZgscrkmsyaPWZK1gLu9ctjzXuOb9tYJ/Mnhxa8Aee5R1zqXC/WhOX0CU3/xW2Ka78zR/UOVOBK6r6xyYRm7@hage8yC1n0UrmxqbPrSZsdlDWyjbbMTa4cpZxrBF740qKWxrnyOYArxkPPcirdVGEAQUAUMgkFoa1SoGkc0X9Lt@@GHFlVzE4F2rXw)

Uses [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s formula.

Comment: Obvious +1 for having the same answer. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Likewise my good man. :-)

Comment: You can use the same golf as my Java answer (credit to _@xnor_): `f(a,b,c){a=a+b>c&a+c>b&b+c>a;}` EDIT: Nvm, @Arnauld already posted that as a separated C answer.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ah, interesting! Ok, I'll stick with what I've got - thanks anyway! :-)

Comment: @ceilingcat Nice one - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), <s>7 bytes</s> 9 bytes (SBCS)

```
|1<+/∘⊏⍖.
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=VHJpYW5nbGUg4oaQIHwxIDwrL-KImOKKj-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)

**Explanation:**

```
## (Top of stack on the left)
## Stack: [1 3 2]
         .   # Copy input
## Stack: [1 3 2] [1 3 2]
       ⍖    # Index array by descending value
## Stack: [1 2 0] [1 3 2]
      ⊏      # Order the input
## Stack: [3 2 1]
    /∘       # Put the elements on the stack 
## Stack: 1 2 3
   +         # Add the top two items
## Stack: 3 3
  <          # Test whether the second item is less than the first
## Stack: 0
|1           # Function signature
```

Edit:
Added function signature (2 extra bytes) to conform to rules. Thanks to [@Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler).

Comment: `f ← |1<+/∘⊏⍖.` works, so adding the signature only takes 2 extra bytes. (auto formatter will insert a space after `|1` but it is still valid without it)

Comment: Also, I think the answer is not valid because the code fragment can only be executed once (not assignable, not possible to push on the stack), which makes it not a function. ([related meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16046/78410)) So you have to include the signature into the answer and count its bytes.

Comment: Thanks @Bubbler, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 8 bytes

```
+/>2*>./
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc09CoAwDIbh3VN8uBT/apu2g4IugpOTVxBFXLz/VJuhREKGJ@@QJ5ZaXZhGKLQwGNN2Gsu@rbHpZ6pn3ceqQHEe94sLlkdAcBmU6KQ4UIbjJrBSiEeKRxAE@IzATeB/fwyGFIWGT9bEDw)

Uses [xnor's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199355/75681)

Comment: +1 simple port, right? :)

Comment: @RGS Yes, it's almost identical to Bubbler's APL solution - it's normal, J is APL's relative.

Answer (score 3):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), <s>128</s> 120 bytes

```lua
b=io.read()t={}for r in b.gmatch(b,"([^,]+)")do
table.insert(t,r) end
print(t[1]+t[2]+t[3]+0>math.max(t[1],t[2],t[3])*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBCsMgEIXhfU4hWTnNII1ZpxcRC1ptIyQaplMolJ7dxm4e/Hzw1per1c@pKIouSOD5870XEiRSFl49Nse3RXrspbmiHaCHUDp2fo0q5WcklowEIubQ7ZTykWa0AxvdZrLD@XI8LGpz779gE2wCJw21jqhx@gE)

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 37 bytes

@Jo King's solution using TIO properly and following the rules of the challenge.

```lua
a,b,c=...print(a+b+c>math.max(...)*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/USdJJ9lWT0@voCgzr0QjUTtJO9kuN7EkQy83sUIDKK6pZaT5//9/0/9m/80B)

[Very direct translation of @xnor's algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199355/42248)

Comment: Hey there, if I understand correctly, you are spending quite some bytes reading from input and extracting the integers. Can't you define a shorter function that already takes the integers? And then you do the IO parsing in the header section of TIO?

Comment: @RGS, Yes, absolutely. I can post a solution like that in the comments. Just gimmee a bit....

Comment: no need to be in the comments! Rewrite your answer. In this community, and for code-golf, you can usually just write the function that does what is asked, as long as your function accepts the input as specified by the OP. I can't really elaborate on it now nor exemplify with Lua because I don't know lua, but I'm sure you can reduce your byte count by a lot if you do what I mean

Comment: @JoKing, I've really got do some study and wrap my head around how to use TIO's header properly.

Answer (score 3):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 13 bytes

```
raJ++j>]2.*.>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/Z@TV/2/KNFLWzvLLtZIT0vP7n9tbvT/aEMdBRCK5QKxjHQUjIEsI7CYMUTMGCgMZBmDZQ0hLEOImBFYDCproqNgCmGZAjlAlilYL5RlAjXPQEfBEsYEsg3BOBYA)

```
ra # Read as array
J  # Duplicate
++ # Sum
j  # Swap
>] # Maximum
2.*# Double
.> # Greater than
```

Comment: +1 good job working on this :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 54 bytes

I haven't written Wren in a long time...

```
Fn.new{|x|x.reduce{|a,b|a+b}>x.reduce{|a,b|a>b?a:b}*2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFkcUpSZmJeek6pgq/DfLU8vL7W8uqaipkKvKDWlNDm1uiZRJ6kmUTup1g5NyC7JPtEqqVbLqPZ/cGVxSWquXnlRZkmqBsJEveTEnByNaEMdIIzV1PwPAA)

Comment: I have never seen Wren around here, for the short time I've been around

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 40 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld):* stores the result of `max` in `a`. Eliminates the variable `m` used in the previous solution.

```c
f(a,b,c){a=a+b+c>2*((a=a>b?a:b)>c?a:c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZHfboMgFMbveYoTliYw6eaferFa7d2eYHfOC8S6knS6oF3SNT67Y8dsjWUpgZwvv/MdOIBavik1jjWTohSKn2UqvdJTWXjPmNVZuZXrkmfKBsWTYbzTjTocqx1sur7S7cM@I0Q3PbxL3bDPVlecnAnY8QOlMXmRRwWkiKYEKggEThjEHIYCojkM0Rk5zsia5zDC8sCBgeMM0emWrwTEDowtn8MYT3fhyu3TF/D0D7U4wPWbGBKCsW4Nw7dTkIKf2LCBTn/tWvtDxvDHi879gtu85wG/et0PYzeoGV1UAqYFywwW3WtDBf6JKmzxnwwuMiwubd4cUwc39uGwBfpijv3@RGEN9FkeuhPlyXRZMozf)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 42 bytes

```c
f(a,b,c){a=a+b+c>2*(a>b?a>c?a:c:b>c?b:c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZHNboMwDMfveQorUyUy0o2PchgUuO0JdmMcQihrpA6mQCd1Fc/OMqOtoplqJbL189@JE8v1m5TT1DiCV1yys0iFW7kyC@4dkVW5yGQuYhlXxlexZMk43alWHo71Drb9UKvuYZ8RotoB3oVqnc9O1YycCRj7gULroizCElJEcwIj8DkuGPkSBhzCJQxQGVrK0IiXMMRy34K@pQxQaZdvOEQWjAxfwghvt@HG7tPj8PQPNdjH/ZsYE4K@6bSDfychBS8xbgu9@tp1ZkZas8dLXHglM3nXBXb1ux/aHNA4dFVzmDesM1j1ry3lOBNZmuK/0L@EQXlp86bNHdw4h0EO9EUfh/2JQgz0WRz6E2XJ/FgyTt8)

Comment: Good solution +1! It is a shame that the `m` doesn't save you anything...

Answer (score 3):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 89 bytes

Array/`vector` solution as shown in other answers.

```cpp
#import<regex>
int f(std::vector<int>v){std::sort(&v[0],&*end(v));return v[2]<v[1]+v[0];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLNboQgEIDvPsXEJi60bOLPeqgae@sT9Lb1YBS3JqsYROJm47NbxP4pJRrkm2@YCVJ03fFSFPP8UDcd4yLh9ELH1KpbARXqRRlFkhaC8USRVOK7Rr0ykSPPbkacR9qWSGIccyoG3oI8@1kiz172tMTjSe3cFtehpJDUrBec5k1q6f2bvG6RZHWJrbsFavwtty@dgtTOauov8Ih@YCJb6BMIttDXZmCYgZK3MNDpngE9w/S1aaafCIQGDBXfwlBXN@HJ7NMl8PwPVdjT73dgii09V4yjfBAMnBEikHh3cPpoCzYISBIY1U9aZpuAva693drPfjJ/x2LAMV0dVKERwwvYb3wQHzdbFbVf82t/s/ESPry3h3htcO3v66a4sTXNnw)

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 56 bytes

```cpp
int f(int a,int b,int c){a=a+b+c>2*((a=a>b?a:b)>c?a:c);}
```

Like the C solution but with more boilerplate.

*-2 bytes thanks (indirectly) to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDNboMwDIDveQqLSWuyphI/7WHA0tueYLethxDohtRCBQG1qnh2lhhtHc0isJ2Pz8GKOp1Wn0qNY1lp2FMbJbcxw6jYVb7IZbZUInyi1NQi28o4Y0KZpFgyjA9lpQ5dXkBa1q1uCnkU5Mb6Qum6EYTY046yrGhflzkjVwJmtTqP40lJ/9ZGFgJ6dCYTKwg4PjDwOQw5RHMYohk5ZmTkOYywPXBg4Jghmm77msPGgRvD53CDf3fh2p3T5/D8DzU4wPfnw5AQzPu6obLTNTyeIYae3V0cXq2qOw1pCud3f2ezx8Gb9sHdPtz9dt6WNWAlJofuqT2GYzPHFgZb8N6aTn9dPDOD9yoP7cVj1l58VItkmncatyl011TgJ2QYvwE)

Comment: Good job on this one! +1 can you please explain me why you need the `#import`?

Comment: @RGS Because functions (like `std::sort`) are not implicitly declared in C++, and `std::vector` is not a builtin.

Answer (score 3):

Never done one of these before. Here are two algorithms borrowed from other answers implemented in JavaScript.

## JavaScript, 32 bytes

```js
(a,b,c)=>a+b+c>Math.max(a,b,c)*2
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##fc9NDoIwEAXgvaeYJZWRMFQSXcANPMTQUH@CYKASb1/bxpiY2CbTTb/XyeuNV17UfH2Y3XqwahoXAxoamzF2qETTct7lqj2xuRR3fn2ut1WITkNfDNM50xkh@BEIZn72YvOrFYKfiEqEPUId19oFIupIJtVtlhGlEuGY4FDaq@Zh@fcnSjCFYlWMZVhOCabEaypddQrnG7Fv)

## JavaScript, 28 bytes

```js
(a,b,c)=>a=a+b>c&a+c>b&b+c>a
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##fc9BCsMgEAXQfU8xqxDJtGRiA@1C7zJKLC2hKdHm@qm6KBSqMLp53@H74I29Xe@vcNwuu12ePoADtbeMBq1QmhV3RtuGO6tNY@LNObbM02lebq1rCSGNQAjrexKHXx0Q0hRUIpwRxrKOMVDQSLKqcbMsKPUI1wrn0kkdz/7fn6jClIsNJZZ5OVWYKq@pj9Upn29k/wA)

Comment: Really good job James! +1 And welcome to the site :D

Comment: Why need the  `a=`?

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 20 bytes

```
=SUM(A:A)>MAX(A:A)*2
```

Input in `A1`, `A2` and `A3`.

---

Alternatively, with input on `A1`, `B1` and `C1`:

```
=SUM(1:1)>MAX(1:1)*2
```

Comment: Cool submission! :D +1

Comment: Interestingly, `SUM(A:A)` is exactly the same number of bytes as `A1+A2+A3`

Answer (score 3):

## [Pepe](//github.com/Soaku/Pepe/), 93 bytes

```
REeEREeEREeEREEEEeEeEREEEeREEEEEEEREEEEEEEErREEEEEerEEEEEerEeEeErEEEEeeRErREErEEEEeREeReEreEE
```

Input: `a;b;c`
Output: `-1` for falsy, `1` for truthy

**Explanation:**

```c
REeEREeEREeE # Push 3 inputs (num) -> (R)
REEEEeEeE # Sort the (R) stack
REEEe # Move pointer pos to the last -> (R)
REEEEEEE # Move last item of (R) (num c in this case) to (r)
REEEEEEEE # Sum the stack (note: does not remove the stack completely!) -> (R)
          # For some reason, the pointer pos of (R) keeps sticking to the last item
rREEEEEe # Subtract active item of (R) (a+b) to (r) (num c) -> (R)
         # ((a+b)-c)
         # r flag: Preserve the items
rEEEEEe # Same as above, but put it to (r)
        # This switches the expression: (c-(a+b)) or -((a+b)-c)
        # No more r flag this time, so remove these two items
rEeEeE # Absolute of (r)
rEEEEee # Divide active item of (R) (a+b) and (r) (num c) -> (r)
RE # Push 0 -> (R)
rREE # Create loop labelled 0 -> (R)
     # r flag: Skip until Ee (or REe)
  rEEEEe # Decrement (0 -> -1) -> (r)
  REe # Return to where a goto was called last
ReE # If the division of (r) returned 0, go inside the loop
reEE # Output (r) as number
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#RRRRv!pE7Sf@&1&0@y_w&@F-gDBM)

Comment: Really funny solution! +1 good job!

Answer (score 3):

## x86-16 machine code, 21 bytes

```
8B D0       MOV  DX, AX     ; DX = a 
03 C3       ADD  AX, BX     ; AX = a + b 
3B C1       CMP  AX, CX     ; is a + b > c? 
76 0C       JBE  NOT_TRI    ; if so, not triangle 
03 C1       ADD  AX, CX     ; AX = a + b + c 
D1 E2       SHL  DX, 1      ; DX = 2a 
3B C2       CMP  AX, DX     ; is a + b + c > 2a? 
76 04       JBE  NOT_TRI    ; if so, not triangle 
D1 E3       SHL  BX, 1      ; BX = 2b 
3B C3       CMP  AX, BX     ; is a + b + c > 2b? 
        NOT_TRI:
C3          RET             ; return to caller
```

Callable function, input `AX`, `BX` and `CX`. Result is in `ZF`: `NZ` if triangle, `ZR` if not.

Uses [Arnauld's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199368/84624) to check.

**I/O from DOS test program:**
[image]

For some reason the test program returns `"Hotdog"` if a triangle and `"Not Hotdog"` if not.

Comment: Nice submission! Are you being serious with the "for some reason" or did you make the program return (not) hot dog for Truthy and Falsy? :)

Comment: @RGS okay, you got me, maybe it was [kinda intentional](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACmydtFDTGs).

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
∑½<A
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oiRwr08QSIsIiIsIlsxMDAsIDEwLCAxMF1cblsxLCAyLCAzXVxuWzIsIDEsIDNdXG5bMSwgMywgMl1cblszLCAyLCAxXVxuWzMsIDEsIDJdXG5bMiwgMiwgMl1cblszLCA0LCA1XVxuWzMsIDUsIDRdXG5bNSwgMywgNF1cbls1LCA0LCAzXVxuWzEsIDEsIDFdXG5bMTAsIDksIDNdIl0=)

Answer (score 3):

## C# 35

```
bool t(int[] s)=>s.Max()*2<s.Sum();
```

:)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
Σ\╙∞>
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///c4phHU2c@6phn9/9/tKEOEMZyAWkjHWMgbQTkG4P5xjpGQBpIguWNgDSEb6JjCqZNdUyAtClQHYQ2gegz0LGEMgx0DEEoFgA)

Exact port, including same explanation, as [my 5-byte 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199354/52210): sum; swap; max; double; a>b.

Comment: But in this case, it is shorter!

Comment: @RGS What do you mean? Both are 5 bytes, and the exact same explanation.

Comment: I meant your original O5AB1E one was 6 bytes :p

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 14 bytes

A port of the Ruby answers.

```
~.{+}*\$)\;2*>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v06vWrtWK0ZFM8baSMvu//9oQwMDBUMQigUA)

### Explanation

```
~              # Evaluate the input
 .             # Copy it twice
  {+}*         # Sum the input
      \$       # Sort the other input
        )\;    # Select the last item
               # in the sorted list
           2*  # Double this item 
             > # Compare
```

Comment: Good job on this answer!

Answer (score 2):

### [W](http://github.com/a-ee/w) `d`, <del>12</del> 10 bytes

I'm quite satisfied because W doesn't have a max function. OR a function sorting the array.

```
▼╪m╜w♣S×∟╖
```

### Uncompressed:

```
<a&b|R       % Max.
      2*     % Double.
        S    % Swap.
         +r  % Sum.
           < % Less than.
% It's in the wrong order because
% I can golf a few bytes off the max function.
```

```
% BTW the max function is implemented like this:
(b<a) && (a) || (b)
% The reduction reduces this function over the whole list.
```

Comment: Impressive first answer and very well presented. welcome!

Comment: @J42161217 ditto!

Comment: I feel like there was another higher-up user named a'_' that went missing recently. Hmm...

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hr`,  <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
÷⑭$->
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////8PZHE9eq6Nr9/2/IBYT/dZNz/@tmFAEA)

Woot! [Port of the 5-byte golfscript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199384/78850). TIO won't work because the version stored has a bug with the `⑭` command, while the most recent version doesn't. (For those interested, I believe TIO is ~20 commits behind the official repo).

This gets converted into the following python program:

```python
from KegLib import *
from Stackd import Stack
stack = Stack()
printed = False
item_split(stack)
sort_stack(stack)
swap(stack)
maths(stack, '-')
comparative(stack, '>')
if not printed:
    raw(stack)
```

### Explained

```python
÷
```

First, we take the sides as input. <s>Keg doesn't do lists very well at the moment (I'm working on improving that though), so each number needs to be taken individually. The `¿` takes the input and evaluates it as a literal.</s> Forget I ever said that. One can actually take a list as input lol. So instead of taking three individual numbers, we go ahead and item split the implicit input list.

```python
⑭$->
```

Then, like the golfscript answer, we sort the stack (`⑭`), swap the top two items (`$`) subtract those two items (`-`) and then finally compare the two with `>`.

Comment: Kool answer! +1 To bad you have to spend three bytes reading the integers!

Comment: @RGS whatever do you mean by spending three bytes to read the integers? :P

Comment: Nevermind me :) Can't upvote anymore today :( will try to remember to do it tomorrow!

Comment: @RGS I know that feeling :P.

Comment: one up!! Go work on those lists now!!!

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
å·b→1.R
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=86fa621a312e52&i=[2,2,2])

Comment: Haven't heard of Stax before! Good work on this +1

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 26 bytes

```r
function(x)sum(x)>2*max(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P600L7kkMz9Po0KzuDQXSNoZaeUmVgAZ//8naxjrmOiYagIA)

If the sum of 3 numbers is greater than twice the greater of those numbers, then the triangular inequality holds.

Comment: De facto! Thanks for the R submission! +1

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 20 bytes

```julia
f(s)=all(sum(s).>2s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P02jWNM2MSdHo7g0F8jUszMq1vzvUJyRX66QphFtqGOkYxyryQUXMNYx0TFFFjACqjBCFjA0MNAxBKFYzf8A)

Comment: Nice and simple Julia submission +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Go 1.21+](https://go.dev), 46 bytes

```go
func(a,b,c int)bool{return 2*max(a,b,c)<a+b+c}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZLdSsMwFMfxcnmKs8KgcbHYuoGK8Rm82N0cknbJKK7pSE9FKX0Sb4bgQ81rH8Q02VeFfJ1fTs755ySfX6tyuxtuRPYqVhIKkWuSF5vSYBSoAgNC3oQBxb9rVFe3u0jVOgsFS1kGuUaaluW6MRJroyG5LMS736MPYpyOs9af-rn47Y654CGFhqCssIJ7DvPFrCFNzMA3NLVsmQMJgxsGSqwrRxK3f068mZwRb8Z9Evd9Emcmp1TWZcJg2gNTxw5g6hL1wcSxo9xrBnf_iEXxvh-St4Q8GVu0tQ4DzjmkcpVrsKuAElUaeGHY1cQIbR_Cl6ghokMqxEgwjFLbM0pyBRhJGHIQ1mPggqowmI-W4NoC-COMEMIRUjs_68AqOwVgIDpbusHmB0GttrYvDqRewl6cFY4fGwkzqOwFM-ySHr8AGUjofgHZP_Z26-c_)

This code works only in Go version 1.21 or later, due to the new `min` and `max` builtins introduced in that version.

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), 8 bytes

```
>×2⊃/↥/+
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgPsOXMuKKgy_ihqUvKwpmWzEgMSAxXSAgICAgIyBUcnV0aHkKZlsxIDIgM10gICAgICMgRmFsc3kKZlsyIDEgM10gICAgICMgRmFsc3kKZlsxIDMgMl0gICAgICMgRmFsc3kKZlszIDIgMV0gICAgICMgRmFsc3kKZlszIDEgMl0gICAgICMgRmFsc3kKZlsyIDIgMl0gICAgICMgVHJ1dGh5CmZbMyA0IDVdICAgICAjIFRydXRoeQpmWzMgNSA0XSAgICAgIyBUcnV0aHkKZls1IDMgNF0gICAgICMgVHJ1dGh5CmZbNSA0IDNdICAgICAjIFRydXRoeQpmWzEwIDkgM10gICAgIyBUcnV0aHkKZlsxMDAgMTAgMTBdICMgRmFsc3k=)

Shorter than [Matthew's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266096/78410) as a proper function.

`sum of the two smaller ones > the largest one` is the same as `sum of three > twice the max`.

```
>×2⊃/↥/+    input: a vector of three numbers
   ⊃/↥/+    evaluate the max and the sum
 ×2          double the max
>            is the sum greater than double the max?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-alp` `-MList::Util=max,sum`, 18 bytes

```perl
$_=sum(@F)>2*max@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ra4NFfDwU3TzkgrN7HCwe3/f0MFIOQyVDBSMOYyArKNgWxjBSMuIAaKGwNFjIDiRmAREwVTIGmqYMJlClQDIk1A6g0ULMGUgYIhCP3LLyjJzM8r/q@bmFPwX9fXJ7O4xMoqtCQzxxZopw7QBQA)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-alp`, 32 bytes

Otherwise without imports

```perl
/ .* /;$_=!grep$_*2>=$`+$&+$',@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrBCsIwEETv@YoRFoXW2maTHKRUPPkb1UMRodhQ/X7XSZmd2eExeVrnZNbiVKHtZRx2z3XKMlZ6GeRey76Ww/F6M/OgnIciOGUP7AHqaPJAouS6kYjETIgucVMyln2H8/Y6@HK/JX9fy/tjzWPOfw)

Comment: +1 for your answer, and I had never seen people doing "imports" with flags! Amusing :D even though it feels unfair :(

Comment: iv'e added another answer without using imports

Comment: you are welcome to use "imports" in the flags! I was just thinking it is quite nice that you can "get away" with it :)

Comment: meta on imports https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4776/how-do-we-count-compiler-interpreter-flags

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 31 bytes

```
func[a][(sum sort a)>(2 * a/3)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc5NCoMwEAXgtZ7i4UoLRRN10S48RLfDLIJJaPGXqOdPo9WSgfl4kwlxRvuX0cSxfcLbbWxJMaXLNmCZ3AqVNanEDSovM/Z2cka1b3QgEgiHY0RBEiXHEUiG7KfQIQ@Fvt87JM5MhuyaVqhP1agO1WH3UnW9V@DxZwGxFzPN7jOuoFnpvDd2xTD1OvxOCCT3JoFFx@y/)

A port of [*@xnor*'s algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199355/52210)

Thanks to S.S. Anne for finding an unnecessary newline!

Comment: Is a/3 the third element of a? Because it looks like you are dividing by 3 :O

Comment: @RGS Haha, yes - it really is the third element (notice the lack of spaces around `/`) This is `path` notation in Red, used for indexing, navigation in hierachical structures, map keys, object fields and so on.

Comment: thanks for the clarification!

Comment: [31](https://tio.run/##Pc5NCoMwEAXgtZ7i4UoLRRN10S48RLfDLIJJaPGXqOdPo9WSgfl4kwlxRvuX0cSxfcLbbWxJMaXLNmCZ3AqVNanEDSovM/Z2cka1b3QgEgiHY0RBEiXHEUiG7KfQIQ@Fvt87JM5MhuyaVqhP1agO1WH3UnW9V@DxZwGxFzPN7jOuoFnpvDd2xTD1OvxOCCT3JoFFx@y/) without the trailing newline.

Comment: @S.S. Anne Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-e`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Ñ<Wx
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWU&code=0TxXeA&input=WzEsMiwzXQ)

Comment: for a simple answer. What does "transpiled JS" mean in the Japt console? (Btw looks like the cockpit for a spaceship! +1)

Comment: No, it needs to be UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>8</strike> 6 bytes

```
<yeSQs
```

<strike>Kinda unfortunate that pop is two bytes :'(</strike>

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @RGS

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/36YyNTiw@P//aGMdEx3TWAA)

Comment: Good job on the Pyth answer, but then wouldn't it be better to use [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199355/75323) formula?

Comment: @RGS Not sure how I missed that, saved 2 bytes, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
›Σθ⊗⌈θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMO9KDWxJLVII7g0V6NQU0fBJb80KSc1RcM3sSIzFywGBNb//0dHm@oomOgoGMfG/tctywEA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as an array and outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for true, nothing for false. Uses @xnor's algorithm. Explanation:

```
  θ     Input array
 Σ      Summed
›       Is greater than
     θ  Input array
    ⌈   Maximum
   ⊗    Doubled
        Implicitly print
```

Comment: +1 for your work, isn't there a way for you to shave one of the `θ` by using the input implicitly as the argument?

Comment: @RGS Maybe, but not in verbose mode, I don't think.

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 29 bytes

Returns 1 for true and 0 for false

```sql
DECLARE @ table(x INT)
INSERT @ values(1),(1),(1)


SELECT-sum(x)/~max(2*x)FROM @
```

Comment: Interesting submission! +1 for that :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
§<ΣoD▲
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9Bym3OL810eTdv0////aEMdIIwFAA)

Comment: Seems fine, just @ed you in TNB

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 7 bytes

```
sum(Ans)>2max(Ans
```

Takes input as a list in `Ans`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
Ṗ'ḣ∑≥
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4bmWJ+G4o+KIkeKJpSIsIiIsIlsyLCAzLCA1XVxuWzIsIDQsIDVdXG5bMiwgNCwgNl1cbls5LCAxMCwgMTFdIl0=)

Returns an empty list for valid triangles, nonempty for invalid ones. Fun fact: This works for any polygon.

```
Ṗ     # Permutations
 '    # Filtered by
  ḣ   # Head
    ≥ # Is greater than or equal to
  ḣ∑  # Sum of the rest
```

Comment: [Get outgolfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250738/92689) (it's completely different tho, not a golf of this)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `M`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
S½<
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
S½<  # Implicit input
S    # Sum the list
 ½   # Halve it
  <  # Compare
     # Minimum
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## PIC16F88x Machine Code, 12 words (168 bits)

<sub>*Still haven't figured out a good way to list these 14-bit words.*</sub>

```
00100001110000 00011101110001 00001011110010 01100000000011
00000000001000 00110011110010 01011111110010 00011101110010
00001011110000 01110000000011 00001011110001 00000000001000
```

Takes the arguments in memory locations 0x70-0x72. Sets the carry flag if the values could not make a triangle, and clears it if they can.

For instructions whose names end in `F` (except `BSF`), the second argument being 0 indicates the destination is register W, and the second argument being 1 indicates the destination is the first argument.

```
; Move a into W
00 1000 0111 0000 MOVF 0x70,0
00 1000           MOVF
         111 0000      0x70
        0                   0

; Add b to W
00 0111 0111 0001 ADDWF 0x71,0
00 0111           ADDWF
         111 0001       0x71
        0                    0

; Subtract W from c (c' = c - (a + b))
; SUBWF clears the carry flag when the result is negative, and sets it
; otherwise.
00 0010 1111 0010 SUBWF 0x72,1
00 0010           SUBWF
         111 0010       0x72
        1                    1

; If the carry flag (bit 0 of the status register) is set, return.
01 1000 0000 0011 BTFSC STATUS,0
01 10             BTFSC
         000 0011       STATUS
     00 0                      0
00 0000 0000 1000 RETURN

; Bitshift c right, to divide it by 2.
00 1100 1111 0010 RRF 0x72,1
00 1100           RRF
         111 0010     0x72
        1                  1

; Because RRF performs rotation and not sign-extension, the sign bit is wrong.
; Set it.
01 0111 1111 0010 BSF 0x72,7
01 01             BSF
         111 0010     0x72
     11 1                  7


; Add the new value of c to W, so now W is half the sum of the original
; values.
00 0111 0111 0010 ADDWF 0x72,0
00 0111           ADDWF
         111 0010       0x72
        0                    0

; Subtract W from a, setting the carry flag if a is more than half the sum.
00 0010 1111 0000 SUBWF 0x70,1
00 0010           SUBWF
         111 0000       0x70
        1                    1

; If the carry flag wasn't set, try again with b.
01 1100 0000 0011 BTFSS STATUS,0
01 11             BTFSS
         000 0011       STATUS
     00 0                      0
00 0010 1111 0001 SUBWF 0x71,1
00 0010           SUBWF
         111 0001       0x71
        1                    1

; Return with the carry flag set or clear, depending on the values.
00 0000 0000 1000 RETURN
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Headass](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass), 39 bytes

```
U[U^]OUO]ODO^R^DOD]ONE.U(U<)U(U<)U(U<)?
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiVVtVXl1PVU9dT0RPXlJeRE9EXU9ORS5VKFU8KVUoVTwpVShVPCk/IiwiIiwiM1xuNFxuNSIsIiJd) - prints `debug` if the input is a triangle, otherwise does nothing

###### Explanation:

```
U[U^]OUO]ODO^R^DOD]ONE. block 0
U[                      r2 = a
  U^                    r1 = b
    ]O                  enqueue r1+r2 (a+b)
      UO                enqueue c
        ]O              enqueue c+r2 (a+c)
          DO            enqueue r1 (b), r1 = 0 (unfortunate)
            ^           r1 = b
             R^         r1 += c
               DO       enqueue r1 (b+c)
                 D]O    enqueue r2 (a)
                    NE  go to block 1
                      . end block

U(U<)U(U<)U(U<)? block 1
  U    U    U              if  c   b   a
   <    <    <   is less than
U(   U(   U(                  a+b a+c b+c
    )    )    )    continue
                 else terminate
               ? print 'debug'
```

This feels mighty golfable but looping in block 1 would be tricky to pull off shorter... i imagine block 0 is refactorable if i finnick with it more but im not in the mood rn

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 26 bytes

```javascript
g=(a,b,c)=>a<b+c&&g(b,c,a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDhCsIgFIX/7ynur6F0izkLilrv4mRbizHDuUHEnn2pjSBI4Yrc@517OHoXkxikbh9mOx2XeuylaVUPNRFYoqTwSgCMfvoboFnHZ9/pyozaakU3VG4ygxRG3oBUdNWvCqPHjyCZl6ZYPYqruJQbmaYNsS0KukjVD6qrdp1qSE0YgiuKfp0mvzRHcBWgHGGPcAjTgxUEqEU8Sq0zD1CWIZwi2Id21P/ZnzexCGY@WB7C3JuzCGaRbZbZ6Myfr2R5Aw)

Comment: Is this valid if it really only works for Truthy cases?

Comment: @RGS It crashes if `true` and not crash if `false`, and requiring a realistic stack

Answer (score 1):

## [Noulith](https://github.com/betaveros/noulith), 26 bytes

```perl
\a,b,c->2*max(a,b,c)<a+b+c
```

[Try it online!](https://betaveros.github.io/noulith/#Zjo9CgpcYSxiLGMtPjIqbWF4KGEsYixjKTxhK2IrYwoKOwoKc3RydWN0IFQgKGEsYixjLHdhbnQpOwoKdHMgOj0gWwpUKDEsIDEsIDEsIDEpLApUKDEsIDIsIDMsIDApLApUKDIsIDEsIDMsIDApLApUKDEsIDMsIDIsIDApLApUKDMsIDIsIDEsIDApLApUKDMsIDEsIDIsIDApLApUKDIsIDIsIDIsIDEpLApUKDMsIDQsIDUsIDEpLApUKDMsIDUsIDQsIDEpLApUKDUsIDMsIDQsIDEpLApUKDUsIDQsIDMsIDEpLApUKDEwLCA5LCAzLCAxKSwKVCgxMDAsIDEwLCAxMCwgMCksCl07Cgpmb3IgKHQgPC0gdHMpICgKYSA6PSBmICh0LmEsdC5iLHQuYyk7CmlmIChhIT10LndhbnQpIHByaW50KHQuYSx0LmIsdC5jLHQud2FudCxhLHQud2FudD09YSk7Cik7)

Answer (score 0):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang/blob/master), 32 bytes

```
O&<=a+0P+=b+0P=c+0P&<b+a c<c+a b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKSyNLCey4Kq2bMsUyUKKOgJZSG4/gC/IsgyqlWWfJMOyhP3rue6eF41sk7vcLR8kzUy/PtPT3WOi7m0UfXuVZFG6msbDopwmi9d3o6Y5kyaT2lRUPi7jNaI8yW5rU2UyFzTTeJZkMUtTli6yW3o09eyns88fWK8aXn66YH41/MfhBduvhsdn79hP1fDiM@tVxMenlwbt2edTg/Tz2YfDy7/bBWc2Ptrsz97fuF49vAS1YjG6C3Pm8IrBpAJbtYjRiO1Xa2dHv@JiBovk0VeG38PhGg2qIRp0E2jSlCNhjebt@fkpEeHjgJzso2@GIRfvBQHwG7beh@kq5vwqG/Nmk/yAXbkaBxeto/Nj@9t5exiEHe9jJ5jAM4jg0R5OOiGLhhE8J984kLUGgtMB1jicswBlDJpNULQM8yK2OXtqNpKsZMmg2YBZUuoyZ7bKIpgh5gjG5XzpFsvsyh8HT57rPYOMRgLiiB7eHk68eYPikyV7uEvKuFiGUdxswHca2zAP7LYww2Wt6/I6u55d5@zp@Wps8/6rFidTGsmM2dragFmvLM6ECDW7A7PXGUx3OmIG7GzEaRGbE8/CnOgujn5js0XOstV8EueFtIfZSTFNbpNSSQXt6E7P1R6Jt8N6HuswR1re6XDWZZZngQq0NOEsj8tVnjEVJoKNImWwbsN9mCfhJI2VFWBEuniIczsCfcoQ9vUrU8ZFNIoIiC8Wl/AkW1xPgp4LexTo6TXr8ODJAAWSbLpa2rilTGLaZTDaNFikgUJIE2ZcW1ZlU8sSmwbM4IE2ioEQSBvwDZYtw6Jk5V0MwsK8BGK5AY5CFDc04uiJMtY4TS8aC88ep41uVGCQ@Ri6ZbLIwGyMWG8MpkUKkWK1XCLgXEWVmjHhN@MPYDfARhkqlJcZxDGkMIxcablA5ZOlz7mYOMYJTGd9TGNopgoyyoDCVRvtRlPDNF1E9r7n9jg6iNPaCXIwW6VpmD@ajlb7c2Fsz0dLW0YKJf8qW@MmFT1UIZPCNk8Pj96@u/ll5/Tnc8NhU@wk2SrX35S7UxP8/uTyBYllnJPIMJuyf61CNUSx96aKvU0VAoD3lsbiZAsWxLxfZ67TPFOqzFcZ7tBApmGnXBS2ypV0ACC0yyRitDpZza78/bG0Q2x0m9KDNqBYwrEqZzaQgv@7aTptqbxDZchFIesC4FBoAaLACf01uiHr7dX9ROcxFg9Yq8xXcQtiUM9jSML8LIQMggstjKxWBQL6ib7LSkRwfHm7WKSwMqkj8KKvlVvfc8j5cY9MMycbZqZoY/aX2ghBWy7S1DZNdZnnQoX4H0zONkzGKvzh8OOZi7VYBBoMT656nudBOIErMFSjIvkj/lIyfA2MGDW8RQRg5OLDp@de0FMlHTMcVnV80dMXrz0gOD45PXLYDJLjoKFDW@rDNByFSzeNM@oADKxUoyQwg3P3EhjrjFibsLRhwbET6iWgFg8JiwEUlQQXdd6I5su1HSCQknGVQhCmZIxqioekjO5sB5DZ6KsAIyb/IqxT1qHVZ6hFEAQIKHZmkIV5m5yS4mVvWAtZPqAqXFFQA1rmWLqoB70a86cqzKCBotwuFF@A4rrsHDKezdve7zP8qyg/AiVIFRjdxmUK7aPdpr1s4w5hiZwmGR8kM9um/cSGILrL0RYX4pRzsc2BN9hqK7w4tQFC35HQJzpHzAYSkIGyF0GSubOy8m3lj6DXK@@qFeQ0IdY0N0CD0QDxFywXyzizDcVuK29RqwBWBXNRKSEeA9/b/4nmZXNhi45kBqZP0Slo4SBkXezvgBx6BxqhDlCtwsuGSdYJqBXCEwuUXMINckgXQY0SnID5Zs9SwVh58gt4Ev8ObRye9g0/d2q7TreEHcxkG4SnG@EBWtI6Lgb5z1Zf9olbAllnPlmBWmfUFttYg7gqQqPRPq8ay410qFgvqTm0dwtkrB@GTWaAE1ofUy9kUt6qSNUClpc4zKTYl0qYrFnmDsjcIlE4r1DAgyEuPgia2M8adKzdpqtVt4ukY9HmXlO73VBm7b52CrDHhhFn6qjlhvmrslC7r2NC9HrCoI42iPIk5EtMyRhaxvaIbrpR321xT0Vq6PuZiiVf7Dn2v3QYxAYQFU7jKQ@Ulz7fHqpRWKqX7Dp7nQomrr5RFodu1KV3KXOE9Ku7EZ1GtGOrXrdXMDnV7mxBYb08b8HB2cBB7Os2FOZbXHOIJjCFEAPUIJsyZGBdwyUPiQbdLsmTQFHJXN9ogWhZO/1vvgvMm@3A7H6XaXc70z8JzZpD4upAc77p5UDCLlAPWLenUSZagL4H56zbgzPWM4n9H6QeQnqs0QYBkpLevprxFOQEtD/yJNY@p3bFCQj/5vqBoEVyBe4IlGCxxMA3Xhnu4jy2CpYtoIdO0jLJ2EP4CLix6QLupGV8G@fAs1xkcVYmId4i4CQv2EPM7sL7GAilICQv2TzMVhA@j69xFr2bIOIABSFRrNISfzQg5TrhKZKuSaNUrkFm8mmSNfEo72VK72VDNNmwRuXR/TxMsTY@gtfZNI2n7KYy@0ZLecIv0ZgZSipnRiis21VjTuQNSeoYpj/rPDikYF0rfJj0ankxqGfFA2Ye/qF5DJC1L3@BazNBcMBqjSJNuszIhijDE5yq5PqiDiDtTgDVxuiCRnAoMbQW00WfzeN5tMQwy9jo5uD/dWX0F7gyUq7sbPElkL5IVw5eRl9o3WIyLh@wGoGvKXxVQHe22VkNtHsq85gCtHntKv2hL9tqw4HJKVOJ5v/63/DLHGSI0fwDq29S19rcddqgyrr15R@@yKjetrrJIF2jdpvRqZBoUOI4qHEbaRI5kKLT0WzC5F/BPfGrl9lo1rxjZu8i2U7qXTuSGvwHfn/PgOW9uDIERofVMQvQ5h0pkxcPV5@FvVpDeymAXhM6WC95/raSt8d1H@Br7n2a/A8NERqGb9yKSDf/uh0yeyMfPEStnR42SdQgiPgXi/Qiio48CaB9Gs9CSJLgmeowkwwWkyn9iBRGJZQpazeysOfEGc5euMWiMF0DoRuUPyTMwyTDZpWF@W3kklDHge97jj9X0f0S/6Fje2RN/Rr3/M1v7jX3/w0)

The obvious answer.

Comment: You can probably save a few bytes by using subtraction / negation and not adding the zeoes

Answer (score 0):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 3 bytes

```
∑ä<
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6FssedUw8vMRmSXFScjFUaMHNnGhDHSCM5QLSRjrGQNoIyDcG8411jIA0kATLGwPFjcDyRlBxEx1TMG2qYwKkTYHqIbQJRL-BjiWUYaBjCEKxEEsB)

Takes input as a list.

```
∑ä<
∑       Sum
 ä      Divided by 2
  <     Check if every element in the input is less than this
```