# Count regex matches

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression

## Your task

Given a *simple* regular expression, you have to count how many strings of length `n` have a match of length `n` with the given *simple* regex. This will just be a subset of regexs. Like, no lookaheads or named groups or recursion or whatever weird things regexs have.

## Simple regular expression

For the purposes of this challenge, a regex is said to be *simple* if, for one, it only contains characters in the ASCII range `32-126`. Furthermore, it should only use the following functionalities:

- match literal characters, much like the regex `abc` would only match the string "abc";
- match options, like `abc|def` would match "abc" and "def";
- match exactly 0 or 1 occurrence of something, e.g. `https?` matches "http" and "https";
- match 1 or more occurrences of something, e.g. `ah+` would match "ah", "ahh", "ahhh", "ahhhh", etc;
- match any amount of occurrences of something, e.g. `1*` matches "", "1", "11", "111", "1111", etc;
- match between `n` and `m` occurrences of something, e.g. `lo{1,4}l` matches only "lol", "lool", "loool" and "looool". If `n` is ommited, it matches up to `m` occurrences. If `m` is ommited, it matches at least `n` occurrences. Assume at least one of `n` or `m` is present;
- use `()` to group, e.g. `ab(c|d)ef` would match "abcef" and "abdef" (c.f. 2nd item in this list) or `(10)+` would match "10", "1010", "101010", "10101010", etc;
- use `.` to match any character (in the ASCII range `[32, 126]`), so `ab.` would match "abc", "ab9", "ab)", etc;
- use `\` to escape the special meaning of a character, e.g. `ab?` would match "a" and "ab", while `ab\?` only matches "ab?";
- use `[]` as a group of possible characters. Inside the brackets, all characters lose their special behaviours, except for `-` and `\`. This means that, for one, `ab[cde]` is shorthand for `ab(c|d|e)` and secondly, `ab[?+*]` matches "ab?", "ab+" and "ab*"; also related to `[]`:
- use `-` to specify a character range within brackets. The ranges you have to support are `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9`, as well as their subsets, like `h-z` or `3-8`. E.g., the regex `ab[c-g]` matches "abc", "abd", "abe", "abf" and "abg"; Note that `-` has no special meaning outside of `[]` so `a-z` would only match "a-z".

## Input

The input for your program/function/routine/etc should be a string representing the regex and an integer `n`. For the regex, you can further assume:

- all characters that show up are in the ASCII range `[32, 126]`
- if `{n,m}` is used, then \$n \leq m \$
- if `-` is used inside `[]` then the specified range is well-formed

## Output

The number of strings of length `n` that match the given regex. You only have to account for characters in the ASCII range `[32, 126]`.

## Test cases

```
".*", 0 -> 1
".*", 1 -> 95
".*", 2 -> 9025
".*", 3 -> 857375
".*", 4 -> 81450625
"abc", 2 -> 0
"abc", 4 -> 0
"ab|ac|ad", 2 -> 3
"a(b|c)", 2 -> 2
"hell(o|oo)", 5 -> 1
"https?", 5 -> 1
"ho{1,4}ly", 6 -> 1
"ho{3,}ly", 137 -> 1
"[abcde]{,2}", 2 -> 25
"(10)+", 7 -> 0
"(10)+", 8 -> 1
"ab\?", 3 -> 1
"[t7]h[i1][s5] is c[0o]d[Ee3] g[0oO][l1L]f", 17 -> 432
"\+351 9[1236] [0-9]{3,3} [0-9]{2,2} [0-9][0-9]", 17 -> 40000000
"-", 1 -> 1
"\\", 1 -> 1
"[+?*]", 1 -> 3
"Abc([d-z]*|(.H)+)", 11 -> 5132188812826241
"ab|ab", 2 -> 1
".(.(.(.(.|a))))|hello", 5 -> 7737809375
```

---

This is code [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest solution in bytes, wins. If you like this challenge, consider upvoting it... And happy golfing!

Comment: Okay, I count _4_ regex matches. Do I win? :P

Comment: @Lyxal python, 12 bytes, `lambda s,n:4`

Comment: Keg, 1 byte: `4`. :P

Comment: Suggested test case: one containing `{n:m}` without `n` (i.e. `"[abcde]{:2}", 2 -> 25`)

Comment: Was the notion of _simple regex_ an attempt at allowing someone to solve this by other means than brute force? (If yes, I think it's still much too complicated for that, as almost all key features of regular expressions are included.)

Comment: @Arnauld yes D: would you suggest further trimming down the specs of a _simple regex_? To what?

Comment: @RGS I would not recommend to change the spec now. But for another challenge, it might be interesting for instance to just count the number of strings matching a sequence of `[...]`, e;g. `[ac-f][xyz] -> 15`, without `\\` escaping or any other nasty features.

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks for your feedback! And what about the `+*?` "modifiers"? Would you think they make for a good addition?

Comment: I don't know for sure. The more features you add, the less likely you'll get non-brute-force solutions.

Answer (score 6):

## Java 10, <s>356</s> <s>342</s> <s>284</s> <s>275</s> <s>233</s> <s>225</s> 220 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;List S;r->k->{S=new Stack();p("",k);k=0;for(var p:S)k+=(p+"").matches(r.replaceAll("\\{(,\\d+\\})","{0$1"))?1:0;return k;}void p(String p,int k){if(k<1)S.add(p);else for(char i=32;i<127;)p(p+i++,k-1);}
```

Works, but way too slow for \$n\geq4\$.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fVTBcpswEL3nK3Y0nYlkCWyZOG5CbE8O7bQz6fTAETjIIMcKGBiQ07o2135AP7E/4soUpzHOVMzA6u1bvdWuxJN4FtZTnOzVqshLDU9mbq@1Su2eC/0@UH4DOge9lDDfaGlF@TrTF1Eqqgq@CJVtLwAeVKXBa@jjN8jwatHFOou0yjP7Y2vcebpU2SP7L@dzpuWjLBm0xnQKC5jAvrSmiTXdepNMfgNPiyjBxC0wQiwhbjIZuIu8xM@ihOLWIwmd4IIiROyV0NFSVri0S1mkIpL3aYpREGwxC4KYBkFNEEPbwTuOCJnx24FbSr0uM0jc2n3OVQwF/ps2FExlGhKyVQuc3HHi2SKOcUFcmVYSDvLR0uiriTN01R0fjl1SmCwUpSyxOHHrvXthClSs56mKoNJCm08jsTLFbVX8EAQ5FBpAy0pjZPcQGxC3g/AzZHiGOA3S7/9Drk44Yh51wxroNK6BuoE7Ee1EfBaN57uIHNHjAktpKp7v8tx4RqcerYtqdobmW86u6nSD2HXX4bAG5874xIP5gFDE3gTfd1IPgll3i74eh0tf8dCvRiGoCiJ/kIex/0E6ITwa@2vop/whXBjlU40goM6Iw43Ph851CP7AuglNkk7dmkM2bM3m9RJ/TMfqdjIwo4v5dNYLj@BR@X4eYT@2foS9HbY/EWqKy/lZl@bdZti4fXaCmLE7NCc/duBF0PQ8luHWJH@Mrw8n9/WRbZjtxSjNPf3OoL0dzULeptJyZedrbReGo9MMX6JL2jApMluEbIJoQhH8/vkLED1c6sMvBhN7YYuiSDe44ZJ2kpA2jXr/Bw)

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.util.*; // Required import for Stack and List
List S;             // List on class-level, uninitialized

k->r->{             // Method with integer and String parameter and integer return-type
  S=new Stack();    //  Create a new List
  p("",k);          //  Put all permutations of length `k` consisting of printable ASCII
                    //  characters in this list
  k=0;              //  Re-use `k` as counter-integer, starting at 0
  for(var p:S)      //  Loop over all permutations in the List:
    k+=             //   Increase the counter by:
       (p+"")       //    Convert the permutation from Object to String
       .matches(r   //    If it matches the input-regex,
         .replaceAll("\\{(,\\d+\\})","{0$1"))?
                    //    after we've replaced all {,m} with {0,m}
          1         //     Increase the counter by 1
       :            //    Else:
          0;        //     Leave the count the same by increasing with 0
  return k;}        //  And return the counter as result

void p(             // Separated method with two parameters and no return-type, where:
    String p,       //   `p` is the prefix-String, starting empty
    int k){         //   `k` is the length the permutations we want to generate
  if(k<1)           //  If `k` is 0:
    S.add(p);       //   Add the current prefix-String to the List
  else              // Else:
    for(char i=32;i<127;)
                    //  Loop over the printable ASCII characters:
      p(            //   And do a recursive call, with:
        p+i++,      //    The prefix-String appended with the current character
        k-1);}      //    And `k` decreased by 1
```

Some notes:

- Java's regex only supports `{n,m}` and `{n,}`, since `{,m}` could be written as `{0,m}`.
- And Java's [`String#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) builtin implicitly adds a leading `^` and trailing `$` to check the entire String.

Comment: Will wait for further golfing and explanation :D

Comment: Will leave a comment appearing to be commenting on the answer but actually end up being a meta continuation of a now existent joke.

Comment: Good luck with that, hope it beats [my brute-force solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199454/75323)!

Comment: @RGS I doubt it.. Java's regex uses `{n,m}` instead of `{n:m}`, so I have to account for that. In addition, it only supports `{n,}` and `{n,m}` (since `{,m}` can be `{0,m}`). So some bytes are already lost there in comparison to your answer. And Python just has better/shorter builtins in general tbh.. :)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>139</s> <s>[137](https://tio.run/##ZVNRi6MwEH73V4Rw0NjaYoxWW7ZX7uHgHg727TiwObBWW8FGMe7DXvW392bUdMveCJLvy8w3k8ykfm8vlRL3nOzI4V4m1@MpIY2jtvrtynheNUSTQpEzU3aRkyZbXZM2vbCc/rk1/RfqaNu2zrspTm1jSiX4qReelTpj6aVhqb3QBIVSFGoSdc6Y8Bzuhfaz/JKDUnGtq6aFNPc2062GmijYak4d4pLlV8KtEXAEm2BC3oBcz2CBOApCERrGHxjuB@4avZJjasJcg/wH6pK0S07GQQDFjl1qG8Kz6CUrS1Z1VYVkMBV2adta75@J6sYdvy/fgVt/cMIZKS7CiYyhglMmb47XP5JAlYy79gKIcKrM4GgKS46HvTktqrShvMQFl7EOJCk0SWO3kqf4eyYkOcP6VcYl/ylzzD1o@gLOcliIgJNNzD2xliR2lxsJJYp@WnpQ1Lgcfh@x7mgWXZp@QA2HwxOIF/u5NBiu8dsxZfFp@VfOO7b6YS/w8viwGXDh8SiKuBd5a8/nYxeO5jKw62z6usQG67ADlbnrEDoduRtoNw6LrsuiZfSgqG1ZOGE4Sjhkw0htLQJWqFo7pHprYcKQNkGoBmHoMm4WqmWwGqnGIWrgam0CHOPewEYT8@2SywGrKViN2/gmyMuOiDE/Wj5myBm8NvvB1g1GNZ@J/zxyCu/PITfVY803FOvJbfZrhqkQ7Xaoj6@QzH7PevpZgO7oXLj2/R8)</s> 129 bytes

Saved 2 naughty bytes thanks to @Kevin, then 6 thanks to @ovs and then 2 more by rewriting `f`, thanks to @wilkben!

```python
lambda r,n:sum(1for s in map(''.join,i.product(map(chr,range(32,127)),repeat=n))if re.match(f"^{r}$",s))
import re,itertools as i
```

You can [try the smaller test cases](https://tio.run/##ZVNNi9swEL37VwhTiJQowbLi2FmaLj0Ueij0VgqOCo5jb1wcyUjawzb2b09HtrVdthMIem@@njWj7sVelOT3Gh3Q8d4W19O5QJrKB/N8xaxWGhnUSHQtOrxYbH6rRtJm02l1fi4tdmx50VQX8qnCPKYsTgmhuuqqwh4kIU2NdLW5Fra84Dr8ddPDh5AaQoLm2iltwUkbW2mrVGtQAZ3utjLWgJYQbLMMKYrQ@hNiwQSYA/tkRvGIothj7nCWpDz1zHZk2DaJdi6qOJU@LfJo@4r6ouyLsw/gQOFTXxJPxEF4qdoWq14pRyazsIu1nXl8S6gbo9uhfQFu94/jdKIYT2cyBwXnStxoPLw2AZWYRWQFRDor8zib04rT8dF/ratiU3HJGyZykwjUGFTmkRLn/EvFBXqC83eRt@ybqF3vseaWw7ccVzxhaJ@zmO8EyqP1XoBEPszHGERNx/HvX240WRCu/TxAw/H4BuSrx6XwGK7x86nE@Xn9Ryx7vPlKVu7y2OhMGI9ZlmUszuJdvGXTFE7@MtzU8fzrCwLWuwkof9cpTDqL9jButyymaxuLw6MMSRC4xXWr5HZ3XKmHAIE1sjMUqWcLG@Zon@SqQZoLmZyNtBhOE6UpkiPXGZ9AfbgGh87Zw5qJEcs5WU5ueAASfTwgPvV3Vk8dagyvjLyynXZZ@j3xX0QdwiOi6CYHp/nmig3otvixcK0cOhxc/ao1FVr8XAzh@wLhIVzyiNz/Ag) online. My solution generates all strings of length `n` with the generator `g` and then tries to match the regex to the whole string. If the test case is the regex `r`, I use the regex `^r$` to force the match to be on the whole string.

Comment: This fails on any test case that uses the `{n:m}` syntax, since Python regexes don't have that (see the `[abcde]{:2}, 2 -> 0 X` in the results of your test suite).

Comment: @Grimmy you are absolutely right! My problem was that I wrote the challenge believing the syntax I knew was `{n:m}` and didn't even check it. Since there is only one other answer that also benefits from me correcting the syntax to `{n,m}` which was what I intended, I edited the OP. Thanks for being on the lookout! Now the test cases are fine :)

Comment: `g` can be 6 bytes shorter with some rearrangements: `g=lambda n:[""][n:]or(s+chr(c+32)for c in range(95)for s in g(n-1))`.

Comment: -8 bytes using itertools
`lambda r,n:sum(1for s in map(''.join,i.product(map(chr,range(32,127)),repeat=n))if re.match(f"^{r}$",s))
import re,itertools as i`

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 86 bytes

Another brute-force solution taking input as `(n)(regex)`.

```javascript
n=>g=(p,s='',c=127)=>n*!s[n-1]?--c>>5&&g(p,s+Buffer([c]))+g(p,s,c):!!s.match(`^${p}$`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddDdaoMwFAfw@z1FLaVN1FiNiNsgCnsNtTQeP7bRRWm63dQ@u4uD0SrJuTz8@J@PT/7DJZw/@gsRXVWPDRsFS1qGeley3c4FFtAYs0TYlswECYqUEEiSaLttJ@K8fTdNfUYZFBg7fy0X8KtlSe@LX@AdHQ@ba3/bHPEInZDdqfZOXYsa5GO09uw1xqt77fer4GnOAj17iRaOGpxPlzLUy@coDmNdKi9hhpX1tWzgMPDq3yoW6hgqB8D3QMWohmVqalUXV9@ltwlPTHcIL/M8fVjP8EEyP9fEclWP0sAyJ7WL@dDQ8JFysdv4Cw)

#### Commented

```javascript
n =>                      // n = target string length
  g = (                   // g is a recursive function taking:
    p,                    //   p = regex pattern
    s = '',               //   s = current string
    c = 127               //   c = current ASCII code
  ) =>                    //
    n * !s[n - 1] ?       // if n is not equal to 0 and s is less than n char. long:
      --c >> 5 &&         //   decrement c; if it's greater than or equal to 32:
      g(                  //     do a 1st recursive call where:
        p,                //
        s + Buffer([c])   //       the character with ASCII code c is added to s
                          //       c is not passed so that it's reset to 127
      ) +                 //
      g(                  //     do a 2nd recursive call where:
        p, s, c           //       this value of c is discarded
      )                   //
    :                     // else:
      !!s.match(`^${p}$`) //   return true (1) if s matches p, or false (0) otherwise
```

Comment: +1 Looking good! I see you also had to do the `^_$` tweak :)

Comment: I have the feeling you can contribute so many tips to the [JavaScript tips page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) xD I.e. the `Buffer([c])` to convert from integer to character. PS: Why do codegolfers always like to obscure their code? ;) The `>>5` can simply be `>31` (which imo makes it a lot more readable). Not that it matters here, since the byte-count remains the same, but stil.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen `Buffer()` doesn't exist in JS. It's a Node thing. So maybe we need a Node tips page, but I'm not sure there are enough Node-specific tricks to justify it. Or maybe we should include Node in [Tips for Golfing in ECMAScript 6 and above](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37624/58563).

Answer (score 1):

## perl -E, 79 bytes

```
($,,$")=@ARGV;@@="";@@=map{$,=$_;map$,.chr,32..126}@@for 1..$,;say~~grep/$"/,@@
```

Comment: Welcome to this community! Can you please include a tio.run link, so that people can check your code passes the test cases? :)